# Hide a specific product price before login - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have two category products (personal and business). I want to prices from the business category only. If user logged in user will show prices. I tried but it's only work for all category product not specific category product. Please help. Thank you in advance.

```
//Hide specific product price for registered user only
 add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html','woocommerce_remove_prices', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html','woocommerce_remove_prices', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html','woocommerce_remove_prices', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_remove_prices( $price, $product ) {

if( is_user_logged_in()) {

    if( is_product_category('business') || has_term( 'business', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
        return 'Only <a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
    } else {
        return $price;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
    if(has_term( 'business', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
        return 'Only <a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
    } else {
        return $price;
    }
```

Comment: But still in mini cart shows prices without logged in

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the logic to check user logged in was wrong. I must check if the user is not logged in.

```
//Hide specific product price for registered user only
 add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html','woocommerce_remove_prices', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html','woocommerce_remove_prices', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html','woocommerce_remove_prices', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_remove_prices( $price, $product ) {

if( !is_user_logged_in()) {

if( is_product_category('business') || has_term( 'business', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
    //remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    return 'Only <a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
} else {
    return $price;
}
```

}
}

Comment: :D hehehe its okay